# What is clients1.google.com/ocsp?

Tags: post

Website making request to clients1.google.com/ocsp with POST.
Its making 2 requests in the same page. and both requests are identical.

What its for? and why it make same 2 requests?

**Request Header:-**

(Request-Line)  POST /ocsp HTTP/1.1

Host    clients1.google.com

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Content-Length  107

Content-Type    application/ocsp-request

Connection  keep-alive

**Response Header :**

(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type    application/ocsp-response

Date    Sat, 21 Sep 2013 14:08:40 GMT

Expires Wed, 25 Sep 2013 14:08:40 GMT

Cache-Control   public, max-age=345600

Server  ocsp_responder

Content-Length  463

X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block

X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

Alternate-Protocol  80:quic

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

It's probably checking certificate status of various certs in the browser.